# How should I check and validate request format and parameters with flask?

Tags: python, flask

For now, my idea is to validate the below request by writing in decorators.py before the request is passed into the init.py including the endpoints. But Im not sure of how I can write the validation code of request with flask. Would anyone help me write this code ?

This is the http request which will be sent from curl command.

```
AUTH_HEADER=`echo -n ${ID}:${SECRET}|base64`

curl ${URL_HEADER}/oauth/token -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic ${AUTH_HEADER}" –d "grant_type=xxx&scope=yyy"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure, especially when it comes to security - do not try to invent things yourself.

For Flask, there is an excellent package [`Flask-Security`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/) which provides:

- Session based authentication
- Role management
- Password hashing
- Basic HTTP authentication
- Token based authentication
- Token based account activation (optional)
- Token based password recovery / resetting (optional)
- User registration (optional)
- Login tracking (optional)
- JSON/Ajax Support